# UTF-8 to byte representation as a string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, ascii

I have the following piece of code:

```
test = "é".encode('utf-8')
print(test)
```

Now, this would give us: b'\xc3\xa9', as expected. Now I would actually have "\xc3\xa9" as a string. How can I achieve this?

I looked at encoding and decoding methods in Python, but unfortunately they do not result in the desired outcome.

Comment: Your requirement seems extremely dubious but decoding it as CP1252 even though it isn't really will achieve what you are asking. The vast majority of scenarios where somebody *wants* to do this, they are doing something very wrong. Why do you want this?

Comment: Or are you looking for `repr(test)`?

Comment: I think I am looking for repr(test) indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use both `repr()` or `str()`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
test = "é".encode('utf-8')
print(test)

# using repr()
my_string = repr(test)[2:-1]
print(my_string)

# using str() 
my_string = str(test)[2:-1]
print(my_string)
```

output:

```
b'\xc3\xa9'
\xc3\xa9
\xc3\xa9
```

Just a little background to this.

The `repr()` function will call the `test.__repr__()` method of the bytes object `test`. And the `str()` function will call the `test.__str__()` method of the bytes object `test`, if `__str__()` is defined, else it will call the `__repr__()` method instead.

This can easily be seen, consider this code:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'repr'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'str'

m = MyClass()
print(str(m))
print(repr(m))
```

output:

```
str
repr
```

if there is no `.__str__()` defined, consider the following code:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'repr'

    #def __str__(self):
    #    return 'str'

m = MyClass()
print(str(m))
print(repr(m))
```

output:

```
repr
repr
```

More information about `__str__()` and `__repr__()` can be found in the [Datamodel documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)